# Quotation mark are separated whenever he is talking about many signs, is that right?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

[THE SOURCE: New York Times](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/12/31/nyregion/metropolitan-detention-center-brooklyn-jail-signs.html?referer=https://www.google.jo/)

> A section of the wall had been covered in signs. “Happy Father’s Day Chris B.” “Happy Thanksgiving Luchie.” “I Love You Payroll.” “Stay Strong Hubberz. We Got This.” ...

I think each sign depicts one of quoted sentence.

if it were covered in one sign, the quotation marks wouldn’t be separated apart; the quoted part could have been all the sentences quoted inside one pair of quotation-marks:

And goes like:

> A section of the wall had been covered in signs. “Happy Father’s Day Chris B. Happy Thanksgiving Luchie. I Love You Payroll. Stay Strong Hubberz. We Got This.”

And another question i have is: do we Add conjunction like “and” among or between quotation marks?
Like “—-“ “—-“ and “—-“

Answer (score 1):

The quotes all refer to individual signs. Interestingly the confusion here is likely that among English dialects there are a few major differences in punctuation, viz.

The Americans and Canadians use double quotation marks and put commas and periods inside them, whereas British Australian and New Zealand standards vary widely among different style guides and publications - but typically leave all punctuation outside quotations for this reason. E.g.:

> N.American: "Happy Thanksgiving Luchie."
>
> British et al.: 'Happy Thanksgiving Luchie'.

The British and cohort all do the latter as they like to make clear the quote had no punctuation, as in this case. I think this is to convey the actual quote more accurately? The British system here would cause less confusion to you though, I imagine.